# Liferay + LDAP + CAS

Tags: ldap, liferay, single-sign-on, cas

I have to make an intranet that allows users to login and access to another web apps , these web apps are already existing , and to acces to each of every user has a login and password .
So , I have to implement this in Liferay.

First I login into portal and a link will be placed in one of the portlets . When I click on that link , it should redirect me to a web application  without asking me again to login and only 'Sign out' option will be there in that web application.

I used LADP and CAS SSO , so I used Apache Directory Server a an LDAP server and I implemented CAS .
The problem is that I don't know where I store the login and passwords of users.
I used jxplorer LDAP client to explore and find how I can add users and set their login and passwords , but the probleme is how I can add the others login and passwords for the others web apps for every user that login into the portal .

Comment: I know is late, but you solved that problem? i tried use the CAS sso but was impossible, so i did a check with a database in common

Answer (score 0):

Liferay provide complete infrastructure to bind Single Sign On (SSO) over CAS and reading users data from LDAP. About the config of liferay and else: 
http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/CAS+Liferay+6+Integration